# Multiple Tracking onclick link of omniture's s.tl(), Cant figure out

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I am using a omniture jasavscript for Site Catalyst.

In which, I am populating the required variables onclick of a link.

But the problem is I get a multiple (2) tracking on a single click, which is not the ideal behaviour. in these 2 tracking, The FIrst one I get is the old one and right after that I get the second latest tracking.

It seems like it is using the cache memory.

> **UPDATE**

I tried reinitializing the object by using `var s = {};` before and after the use of `s.tl('this','e','',null);`

But it didn't worked

Could someone suggest how it can be rectified.

Comment: do you have any code to show us? I don't know the technology, but it looks like it might be needed for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any code I can only speculate, but my guess is the additional hit is from SiteCatalyst's auto-link tracking - either an exit link because the target URL is not listed in `linkInternalFilters`, or a download link because the target URL ends with something listed in `linkDownloadFileTypes`.

I suspect, given the `'e'` argument of your `s.tl()` example, that the link is an exit link. So on that note.. perhaps the solution here is to piggyback off the auto-exit-link tracking, instead of making your own `s.tl()` call.  Adobe has a plugin called `exitLinkHandler` that will let you trigger additional variables whenever the auto-exit-link tracking occurs.

Here is the plugin:

```
/*
* Plugin: exitLinkHandler 0.5 - identify and report exit links
*/
s.exitLinkHandler=new Function("p",""
+"var s=this,h=s.p_gh(),n='linkInternalFilters',i,t;if(!h||(s.linkTyp"
+"e&&(h||s.linkName)))return '';i=h.indexOf('?');t=s[n];s[n]=p?p:t;h="
+"s.linkLeaveQueryString||i<0?h:h.substring(0,i);if(s.lt(h)=='e')s.li"
+"nkType='e';else h='';s[n]=t;return h;");
```

Within your `s_doPlugins` function, add the following:

```
s.url = s.exitLinkHandler();
if (s.url) {
  // pop your variables here. Don't forget to pop `linkTrackVars` and `linkTrackEvents`, same as you would have done before
}
```

Now, this will make your additional variables pop on *any* exit link triggered.  If you want it to only trigger on certain URL matches, or only on a specific match, you can do this several ways, depending on your needs:

- If you only need to do a general substring match, you can pass some
  or all of the target URL as the first argument for
  `s.exitLinkHandler()` and it will match the passed argument against
  the target URL.
- If this isn't good enough, within the `if(s.url)` condition, you can
  perform your own matching (e.g. regex matching) against the target
  URL using `s.url`.
- If you need to target by some DOM attribute of the link, within the
  condition, `s.eo` is an object reference to the link that was
  clicked, so you can write your own conditions around that.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Omniture does not track links with # as exit links so you can do something like:

```
<a href="#http://google.com" data-track-msg="Tracking Message" class="prepended-with-hash-for-tracking">Search</a>

<script>
(function (){
  'use strict';

  var links = document.querySelectorAll('.prepended-with-hash-for-tracking');

  var track = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = e.currentTarget;
    var url = link.href;
    var trackingMessage = link.getAttribute('data-track-msg');

    // Remove the hash.
    if (url[0] === '#') {
      url = url.substr(1);
    }

    // Track in omniture.
    var s = s_gi('InsertYourRSID');
    s.tl(link, 'o', trackingMessage, null, function(){
      window.location.href = url;
    });
  };

  for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', track, false);
  }

})();
</script>
```

## Option 2

Another work-a-round is to set `s.linkLeaveQueryString = true;` and then append the url with a query parameter containing your domain name which matches a string in `s.linkInternalFilters`. e.g. `<a href="http://facebook.com?r=yourDomain.com">Share</a>`

## Option 3

Disable omniture's default external link tracking by setting `s.trackExternalLinks=false;` and then you can handle all external links with an event handler that calls `s.tl()` with JavaScript similar to option 1.

I would recommend option 3.